# MySQL PHP PDO remote server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can not connect to a remote server with PDO:

```
    public function dbConnection ($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPass){
        try{
            $dbChain = 'mysql:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName;
            $dbh = new PDO($dbChain, $dbUsername, $dbPass);
            print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
            die;
...
```

`errorInfo()` only returns something if I have for instance the wrong user or password. With the right one it does not report anything, but $dbh remains empty.

`errorInfo()`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

`$dbh`

```
object(PDO)#5 (0) {
}
```

It's a remote server, but I have access using for instance MySQl Workbench, from the same machine. For the local MySQL server DB the same code works just fine.

What could be wrong with the remote connection?

**Edit:**

```
public function dbConnection ($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPass){
    try{
        $dbChain = 'mysql:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName;
        $dbh = new PDO($dbChain, $dbUsername, $dbPass);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            $errorCode = $e->getCode();
            var_dump($errorCode);
    }
```

I tried this and I get the same empty result.

```
object(PDO)#5 (0) {
}
```

**Edit2:** Same result.

```
        $dbh = new PDO($dbChain, $dbUsername, $dbPass
                , [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
```

Comment: How do you know that your connection is not successful? What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Did you attempt the new code?

Comment: Yes, the result is empty as well.

Comment: `object(PDO)#5 (0) {}` look like a valid pdo instance to me. What do you expect? And please elaborate on `How do you know that your connection is not successful?`

Comment: You attempted the new code and no errors were reported?

Comment: Well actually I do not know execpt for the fact the other queries work locally and then remotely they do not... So maybe the problem is further... but the DBs are equal.

Comment: "Does not work" is not an adequate description of the problem. Post the code that executes the queries, the output, and the expected result.

Comment: Well the output suggests that the connection itself was established - at least there's nothing that says otherwise; your pdo instance has the object id 5 and exposes 0 properties via its hashtable - perfectly normal for a pdo instance. So the code you've posted likely has nothing to do with the problem; at least it doesn't pin it.

Comment: You haven't shown us the query, how you execute it and  how you loop through the results. We'd need to see that code to help you any further.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a catch, after setting the proper error attributes,  to see if there are errors -

```
try {
    $dbChain = 'mysql:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName;
    $dbh = new PDO($dbChain, $dbUsername, $dbPass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getCode();
}
```

Comment: You can cram those options right into the constructor like: `$dbh = new PDO($dbChain, $dbUsername, $dbPass, [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);`

Comment: What effect do you expect this to have? The connection is established in the constructor, i.e. before the setAttributes are invoked.

Comment: Are you asking me, or Sammitch @VolkerK?

Comment: You, @Jay ;-) and I mean: in the context of the question.

Comment: The OP didn't indicate what error reporting they were using, their `try` was incomplete. Since they said they "can not connect" I approached from the connection first.